# When does the symmetrisation generate an intermediate field?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, symmetry

Consider $L/K$ with Galois group $G$. Define the symmetrisation of $H$ (subgroup of $G$) to be:
$$
\phi_H(x) \;=\; \sum_{h\in H} h(x).
$$

Obviously, this is fixed by H.Moreover, in the case that the characteristic of $L$ is zero,then $$im(\phi_H)=L^H.$$ This is all contained in Jim Belk's answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153410/intermediate-fields-of-cyclotomic-splitting-fields-and-the-polynomials-they-spli/153532#153532)

It often happens that if $\alpha$ generates $L$ over $K$, then $\phi_H(\alpha)$ generates $L^H$ over $K$. In Gerry Myerson's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463968/finding-the-intermediate-fields-of-bbbq-zeta-7?rq=1), he says that you have to be unlucky for this to not be the case. My question is this: exactly how unlucky do you have to be, i.e. in which cases does this not happen?

Comment: You'd need characteristic $p$ and $p\mid |H|$, I suppose

Comment: so when it has char = 0 it always works?

Comment: It can fail in characteristic zero easily enough. Let $K=\Bbb{Q}$, and let
$L=\Bbb{Q}(\root4\of2,i)$ be the splitting field of $x^4-2$. We have $L=K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha=\root4\of2+i$, because $\alpha$ is not a fixed point of any element of the Galois group $G\simeq D_4$. Let $\sigma\in G$ be the automorphism determined by $\sigma(i)=-i$
and $\sigma(\root4\of2)=-\root4\of2$. You can easily verify that $\sigma$ is of order two. If $H=\langle \sigma\rangle$, then $L^H=\Bbb{Q}(i\root4\of2)$. But $\phi_H(\alpha)=\alpha+\sigma(\alpha)=0$ so $K(\phi_H(\alpha))=K$.

Comment: I think that you can characterize this phenomenon using a normal basis of $L/K$. It's getting late here, so I won't think it through now, but my guess is that for the process to fail $\alpha$ has to be an element of a finite union of proper $K$-subspaces of $L$. I guess that Gerry had something similar in mind.